# Catching exception in constructor

Tags: java

```
public class AnimalException extends Exception {
    public AnimalException(String error) {
        super(error);
    }
}

public class Zoo {
    private String animal;
    private String food;

    public Zoo (String animal, String food) throws AnimalException {
        this.animal = animal;
        if (findWord(animal, "wolf")) {
            throw new AnimalException("This animal is a predator.");
            //something ought to be done here, I reckon
        }
        else {
            this.food = food;
        }


    }

    public static boolean findWord(String word, String find) {
        int total = 0;
        int idx = 0;
        while ( (idx = word.indexOf(find, idx))!= -1 ) {
            total++;
            idx++;
        }
        if (total == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
}
```

What I would like to do is when a `wolf` is caught in the constructor the value for `food`is changed automatically to something else. I did try using `getter-setters`, however, I get the error of `unreachable code`.
What do I do?

Comment: Where does your code crash?

Comment: Throwing an exception generally means "panic and exit this code immediately right from here, leaving things as broken as they are at this point". Particularly, when throwing from a constructor, the result of the `new` operator will not be usable, as code flow is interrupted by the exception. You throw exceptions when you encounter a state that you cannot or don't want to handle. Are you sure that's what you want to do there?

Comment: Throwing exceptions is not the best way to communicate with user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your desing is, that caling `throw exception` leaves the scope of the blocks and is looking for `try-catch` block which could handle the exception. In your case

```
void foo() {
    if (somethingbad()) {
        throw new exception();
        bar(); // <-- unreachable code, since throw leaves foo function.
    }
}
```

If you throw an exception in constructor and the exception leaves the function, because there is no `try-catch` for that exception in constructor, the construction of that object fails. So, if your `Zoo` prohibits having a wolf as an animal, you should throw exception (thus `Zoo` will never be created at all).

```
public Zoo (String animal, String food) throws AnimalException {
    this.animal = animal;
    if (findWord(animal, "wolf")) {
        throw new AnimalException("This animal is a predator.");
    }
    else {
        this.food = food;
    }
}

void foo() {
    Zoo myZoo;
    try {
        myZoo  = new Zoo("wolf", "meat");
    } catch (AnimalException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString())
    }
    // myZoo is still null, uninitialized.
}
```

However, if you want to have predators in `Zoo`, but with warning to all visitors, you should just display some warning.

```
public Zoo (String animal, String food) throws AnimalException {
    this.animal = animal;
    this.food = food;
    if (findWord(animal, "wolf")) {
        System.out.println("Beware, we have a predator in zoo");
    }
}
```

Also, are you aware, that your `Zoo` may contain only one animal and one food?

One more thing. Your method `findWord(String, String)` is too complicated. Java contains a lot of usefull classes and functions, so that we are not delaying ourselves writing code each time over and over again. Looking for substring of a word is really usefull and favourite function. Take a look at [`indexOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29). It is designed exactly for your purpouse and probably implemented similarly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want some specific logic to be performed when you detect a "wolf", an exception is not the right way. You should only throw an exception if the construction of the instance should fail when you find a "wolf".

```
public Zoo (String animal, String food) {
    this.animal = animal;
    if (findWord(animal, "wolf")) { 
        // put whatever logic you wish here
    }
    else {
        this.food = food;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the constructor also contains the food, sorry, I edited that part. Yes, I understand that it's not good to do it via exception, but this is just for practice and the assignment demands it. It's also pointed out to follow the assignment's instructions to the T even if they seem contradictory. It's all just hypothetical.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set the food value, int the if statement, before you throw an exception, not after? Like this:

```
public Object (String animal) throws AnimalException {
        this.animal = animal;
        if (findWord(animal, "wolf")) {
            this.food = food;
            throw new AnimalException("This animal is a predator.");
            //something ought to be done here, I reckon
        }
        else {
            this.food = food;
        }


    }
```

Comment: My original code does have the food value, but I don't write code in English, I translate it when I post to SOF and I forgot to add it this time. Also, yes, this is the kind of thing I was looking for - I can't read anything like this in explicit form from the API that "you need to set statement Before your throw exception" et cetera et cetera.